# Как активировать время в чате?

Tags: php

iframe:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
      $message = $_POST['message'];

  }

  $db = mysql_connect("", "", "");
  mysql_select_db("bakugan609", $db);
  if (trim($message) != "") {
  $time = time();       
mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (message,username,time) VALUES ('$message','{$_SESSION['username']}','$time')");
  }

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages");

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<br>";

      echo date('H:i ',$row['time']).$row['username'];
      echo "&nbsp;: {$row['message']}";

  }
?>
```

Comment: Нормально вопрос задайте, как минимум что за чат, на чем написан и  в чем собственно проблема, написать "как активировать время в чате?" примерно тоже самое что написать у меня не работает компьютер...

Comment: ок

Comment: @Prikol Редактируйте исходный вопрос вместо добавления комментария с кодом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправь

```
echo "&nbsp;: {$row['message']}";
```

на

```
echo "&nbsp;:".$row['message'];
```

Comment: а разницы между echo "&nbsp;: {$row['message']}"; и echo "&nbsp;:".$row['message'];?<br> Особенно интрестно зачем вообще тут этот тупой &nbsp?<br>Но еще больше интерестно - зачем использовать двойные кавычки если в итоге используется калькуляция строк с переменными?О_о